# Android error implementing ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am trying to create a view pager but I'm stuck in endless loop of fixes so Eclipse changes something which makes something else break and then reverts back to the original error.

I have been following [this tutorial](https://github.com/thecodepath/android_guides/wiki/ViewPager-with-FragmentPagerAdapter) but can't seem to get it working can anyone help me find where I am going wrong?

Here is what I have done so far:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;


public class Menu extends FragmentActivity {
        // ...
    FragmentPagerAdapter adapterViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_level_pager);
        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        adapterViewPager = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        pager.setAdapter(adapterViewPager);
    }


        public static class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private static int NUM_ITEMS = 3;

            public MyPagerAdapter(android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
                super(fragmentManager);
            }

            // Returns total number of pages
            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return NUM_ITEMS;
            }

            // Returns the fragment to display for that page
            @Override
            public MyFragmentAdapter getItem(int position) {
                switch (position) {
                case 0: // Fragment # 0 - This will show FirstFragment
                    return  MyFragmentAdapter.newInstance(0, "Page # 1");
                case 1: // Fragment # 0 - This will show FirstFragment different title
                    return MyFragmentAdapter.newInstance(1, "Page # 2");
                case 2: // Fragment # 1 - This will show SecondFragment
                    return MyFragmentAdapter.newInstance(2, "Page # 3");
                default:
                    return null;
                }
            }

            // Returns the page title for the top indicator
            @Override
            public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
                return "Page " + position;
            }

        }

    }
```

Here's `MyFragmentAdapter`:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class MyFragmentAdapter extends Fragment {
        // Store instance variables
        private String title;
        private int page;

        // newInstance constructor for creating fragment with arguments
        public static MyFragmentAdapter newInstance(int page, String title) {
            MyFragmentAdapter fragment = new MyFragmentAdapter();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt("someInt", page);
            args.putString("someTitle", title);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        // Store instance variables based on arguments passed
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            page = getArguments().getInt("someInt", 0);
            title = getArguments().getString("someTitle");
        }

        // Inflate the view for the fragment based on layout XML
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_level_select, container, false);

            return view;
        }
    }
```

And this is the error I get:

```
The return type is incompatible with FragmentPagerAdapter.getItem(int) Menu.java line 42
```

Comment: probably package importing issue so try to use `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;` instead of `import android.app.Fragment;` in `MyFragmentAdapter` class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager
```

instead of

```
import android.app.FragmentManager;
```

in your My Activity and

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

instead  of

```
import android.app.Fragment;
```

in `MyFragmentAdapter`

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, the problem is in your auto-generated import  for the MyFragmentAdapter. In MyFragmentAdapter, you are using `import android.app.Fragment;` while, try to reference it with `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;` in Menu Class.
 So, my recommendations are to change the reference of fragment in your MyFragmentAdapter. :)